# The Subset Sum Problem: Input: a finite subset S of integers, and an integer t

Tags: np, np-complete, np-hard

The Subset Sum Problem: Input: a finite subset S of integers, and an integer t. Question:
does there exist a subset A ⊆ S such that the members of A sum to t? Suppose you have access
to an oracle that answers queries about instances of Subset Sum. Assuming (S, t) is a positive
instance of Subset Sum, provide an algorithm for determining the set A whose members sum
to t. Your algorithm should make at most a polynomial number (as a function of |S|) of oracle
queries to compute A.

Comment: What would be your programming-related question?

Comment: Its a complexity related question

Comment: It’s not appropriate for this site.